# Keyup Validation - Left/Right Arrows Not Working in IE

Tags: jquery, forms, validation, internet-explorer, keyup

I'm using Jquery to limit the characters that can be entered (specifically on keyup) in a textbox (allow all numbers, decimal points and left/right arrows, but no other characters).

HTML:

```
<input class="decimal" id="id" type="text" name="name" value="" aria-invalid="true">
```

JQUERY:

```
$('.decimal').keyup(function(){
    var val = $(this).val();

    if(event.which>=37 && event.which<=40)
                {
                    return false;

                }

    if(isNaN(val)){
         val = val.replace(/[^0-9\.]/g,'');
         if(val.split('.').length>2) 
             val =val.replace(/\.+$/,"");
    }
    $(this).val(val); 
});
```

This solution is mostly working for me, but I am running into an issue where the left/arrows do not work in IE (but they do work in Chrome, FF, Safari, etc.). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what version of IE and Jquery are you using?

Comment: @roman, Testing on IE8 with Jquery 1.11.1.